# Access network share in Debian?

Tags: networking, debian, network-shares, readynas

I've just gained full root access through SSH to my readyNAS which runs Debian and I am looking into ways of making network shares available directly on the readyNAS.

I guess my syntax is completely wrong, so how should I really map up the following drive to access it in my SSH terminal?

```
\\UBUNTU\www
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if im wrong, but your trying to access a network share in debian?
or are you trying to make a network share accessible from other machines?

this is how to mount one in debian/ubuntu:
`sudo smbmount //HOSTNAME/FOLER /mount/point -o user="username%password",uid=1000,mask=000`

Comment: btw that command is one line

Comment: FYI, the preferred filesystem type is [`cifs`](http://linux-cifs.samba.org/), as in `mount -t cifs //hostname/share /mount/point`, and `smbmount` / [`smbfs`](http://samba.org/samba/smbfs/) are obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

smbmount no longer available, so you should install `cifs-utils`

```
mount -t cifs //HOSTNAME/FOLDER /mount/point -o rw -o user="username"
```

it will ask password